# Queueable entity App\Setting not found for ID error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, queue

I am trying to send emails in `laravel 5.1` by using `queues`. When running queue listen command on terminal,

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Displays below error on terminal,

```
[Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\EntityNotFoundException]  
Queueable entity [App\Setting] not found for ID [].
```

Values of `jobs` table is not process. Any idea ?

How can I process my queue ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a few months old, but I'd like to add an observation of mine while encountering this very same error message. It is due to the EventListener (interface of ShouldQueue in this example for asynchronous) not being able to resolve a dependant variable correctly (out of scope or not included in scope of Event object passed through the handle(Event $event) method of EventListener).

For me, this error was fired when I put my code within the __construct block within the EventListener:

```
    public function __construct(Event $event)
    {
        $localProperty = $event->property

        Mail::queue(etc...);
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // Yeah I left this blank... whoops
    }
```

Instead, the handle() method of the EventListener takes an Event interface and when called processes the job in the queue:

In the Event:

```
    public function __construct(Object $ticket, AnotherObject $user)
    {
        $this->ticket   =   $ticket;
        $this->user     =   $user;
    }
```

And in Event Listener

```
    class SomeEventListener implements ShouldQueue
    {
        use InteractsWithQueue;
        use SerializesModels;

        public function __construct()
        {
            // Leave me blank!
        }

        public function handle(Event $event)
        {
            $someArray = [
                'ticket' = $event->ticket,
                'user'   = $event->user,
            ];

            Mail::queue('some.view', $someArray, function($email) use ($someArray) {
                // Do your code here
            });
        }

    }
```

Although a tad late, I hope this helps someone. Queues are similar to Events (with the exception of Jobs being the main driving force behind Queues), so most of this should be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that it was because a model was added to the queue, that has since been deleted.